# Inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:ísi not set up for use with LaTeX

Tags: utf-8, compilation

I have some tex.'s in Spanish that compiled two years ago, but now I can't get to compile them. The problem is that the compiler don't accept accentuated characters.

Does anybody know which the problem/solution can be?

I tried to write `\usepackage{lmodern}`, but that doesn't work.

Thanks in advance